# Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: oracle, robotframework

I am trying to establish a connection from Azure pipelines to oracle using cx_oracle.

I'm using a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git && apt-get install telnet
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get -y install wget
RUN apt -y install unzip
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/215000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0dbru.zip
RUN apt-get -y install libaio1
RUN sh -c "echo /instantclient_21_5 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
RUN ldconfig
RUN apt -y remove unzip
RUN rm instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.5.0.0.0dbru.zip

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Im doing automated tests using robotframework, i just updated to cx-Oracle 8.3.0. I still get the error

```
DatabaseError: DPI-1047:
Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library:
"libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory".
```

Comment: try appending path to your instantclient to env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So in your dockerfile you can add something like `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/instaclient_21_5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Try the latest version of cx_Oracle (now called python-oracledb) since it doesn't need necessarily need Oracle Client libraries, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)

Comment: Also see [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python).

Comment: @ChristopherJones, how can I connect to database from robotframework? Im new to this. If I use this new python-oracledb module Will I have to modify my keywords. Currently I do it this way:
.

  connect to database using custom params  cx_Oracle  ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}

Comment: @ChristopherJones I did it! I just change the module cx_Oracle to oracledb in my keywords to connect to db, so i did this way: connect to database using custom params oracleedb  ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}